# Can't find Appian Admin Console

Tags: appian

I am new at Appian and eager to learn, so please help me if you can and don't tell me go to search before asking here as I have already searched and found nothing.

I can't find **`Appian Admin Console`** as shown in screenshot, how can I get it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who Google for answer: I used a free trial version and it seems to access to the `Admin Console` is **not included** in Appian Free Trial version.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing where to search, I can provide you the corresponding quote from the [Appian documentation](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.1/Appian_Administration_Console.html):

> Only users of type [System Administrator](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.1/User_Management.html#manage-user-rights-and-security) can access the Administration Console and make changes to the configurations.

Do you know anybody in your organization or from Appian who has that rights and who might grant to them for you as well?

Answer (score 0):

The commmunity version does not include Admin Console.

Answer (score 0):

The community version does provide the Admin Console, but only System Administrators can see it.